# How to get the length of a record from a csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I am using `org.apache.commons.csv` to read a `csv` file. My code looks like this

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
                                               .parse((Reader)arg0.getReader());

for (CSVRecord record : records) {

}
```

How to get the comma seperated string value from each `record` ?

Comment: You have two different questions, one in the title and one in the text. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for (CSVRecord record : records) {

```
currentRecordSize = record.size();
```

// code

}

Answer (score 1):

You may use `size()` and `get(int index)` methods

```
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
    for(int i=0; i<record.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(record.get(i));
    }
}
```

All the [**detailled doc is here**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.5/apidocs/index.html).